# Is there an alternative to <tt> for inline fixed-width formatting in Questions/Answers/comments?

Tags: feature-request, formatting

Many times when asking or answering, or even just commenting, it's desired to have a **<tt>** or similar functionality. For example, when referencing a function or a variable, you would use something like this: `my_function_name`, which outputs `my_function_name`.

Inline, it really throws off the appearance - especially in comments when you reference a few different things. A better, more subtle (yet still obvious) approach would be to allow **<tt>** or some other way to output a fixed-width font to highlight the function, variable, etc.

Note: I accidently posted this over in meta.SO, and at least in their comments, the inline <code> blocks are almost imperceptably highlighted. That would be great here.

Comment: Just as an example, `my_function` is called later in the execution, before `my_other_function`. In Wikis, you can use <tt> and it doesn't `overwhelm` the text with `obscene blocks of color`. It can be quite `ugly` when `overused`.

Comment: if you need to add something to your question, please _always_ use the edit-link.

Comment: @kaiser: Sorry, but I felt that I needed to add the comment to further demonstrate the point of my Question. It wouldn't have the same effect by just *describing* it in the Question. I guess I could've taken a screen shot of the comment, posted the pic in my Question, and then deleted the comment.